# T4MVC and just path without query parameters

Tags: t4mvc

Can I render a url without query parameters with T4MVC without using nullable ints?

```
public virtual ActionResult GetSchoolsForDistrict(int districtId)
        {
            return Json(_schoolsService.GetSchoolsByDistrict(districtId.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do? I don't see the connection between what you're asking and the code snippet.

Comment: The parameter above always has to be supplied when doing Html.ActionLink(MVC.Schools.GetSchoolsForDistrict(0), which appends districtId=0, but would like the link with the query string without using int? districtId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call it without any parameters. e.g.

```
Html.ActionLink(MVC.Schools.GetSchoolsForDistrict())
```

This is because T4MVC always generates an overload with no parameters.